# Is this composition or aggregation or association?

Tags: java, uml

I am writing a job tracking application where the job seeker can apply for jobs and keep track of the records. when i try to design the model using uml , I got a question.

```
Job (class)
---
id:int
position:String
status:String
```

---

```
Comments (Class)
--------
id:int
comment:String
job:Job
```

I was asking myself few questions to understand whether this is a composition or aggregation?

1. Should the comments deleted when the job is deleted? Yes , then is this composition?
2. Job owns comments?  people always ask this question, but we cannot exactly ask this question in this case? Because car owns a wheel? yes , can we ask Job owns comment?

I dont know whether this is an appropriate question. I was worrying so much that I will get minus points in stackoverflow if the question is not appropriate. But I really wanted an answer, hence posting this. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Arun

Comment: It's a question about architecture for code, showing your work so far and asking a specific question. You are at risk of down/close votes for opinion based but I think you are ok overall

Comment: @TimB I think, questions about UML diagrams are almost always opinion based, because many important elements in UML are left undefined strictly. And because on that stage of project developing there are always several different possibilities.

Comment: The question is OK. +1 here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aggregation is a subset of association. Composition is a subset of aggregation. So, putting OR between them is not so correct.

> Should the comments deleted when the job is deleted? Yes , then is
>   this composition?

If they are deleted, it IS a composition. But it is YOU who have to decide how you'll organize your classes. You can make comments not so dependent and it will be a `shared` aggregation or association with `none` aggregation

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion `Job` should refer `Commons` and not the other way around. Your design is more an ER then an UML diagram. And I think the `Comment` shares its life-cycle with `Job`, because if the `Job` is gone, the `Comment` has no context anymore. Hence, it is a composition.

The UML in my opinion is:

```
Job (class)
---
id:int
position:String
status:String
comment:Comment

Comments (Class)
--------
id:int
comment:String
```

Comment: This is what I was going to ask next, I understood now

Comment: Job has many comments, DO you know how to model List<Comment> in modelio tool?

Comment: Yeah, List<Command> should be fine. You have to distinguish between ER and UML. The List<Command> comments should be a property of your Job class, while job_id should be a column of your Comment database table. Using hibernate you would map it as inverse. Here is an [example](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/inverse-true-example-and-explanation/) in case you are interested in how to map / model it.

Comment: I understand that job should have comments. But there is a user table where i save users. Users are able to comment. to find out which user made the comment. Should i have comment field inside user class as well? and I also need to track which user applied for the job, In that case , Job inside user class as well ? confusing :(

Comment: Because if the user deleted , comments also should be deleted right

Comment: I would either suggest `Comment` aggregates `User` to model which `User` is the author of a `Comment` or to track the unique identifier of a `User` (something like a handle) in the `Comment`. The design decision you have to take is: if a `User` disappears, would you like to lose all information about who created the comment? Or even the comment itself, which makes the action untrackable? Or would you like to keep the unique identifier even so the identified `User` is gone. Its a design decision which should reflect the requirements / value the comment add to the `Job`. Hope this will help.

Comment: ya , I'm thinking about it. Users are isolated. if the user account deleted , comments should still be shown. but if the job is deleted comments should be deleted. because the comments are written about a specific job. Finally there will be a comments table with id, comment, user_id, job_id columns. But if the user deleted what user id to have in the column for the particular comment. Just to display the comments of the deleted users , should we have username in the comments table. Because we have to display the username along with the comments when displaying the comments of a particular job.

Comment: @user1448679 - Keeping comments without mapping them to users might break your design.. I strongly suggest you think carefully from a functional perspective. It makes no sense to show comments on a job of deleted users. And how will your DB work i.e, how will you map /join tables based on comment / users?

Comment: I think it is a matter of which aspect is of more value in your domain: to conserve all `Comments` as long as the `Job` exists, while having knowledge about the `User` is of secondary value or to remove the `Comments` together with an `User` because without a `User` the `Comment` is of no value anymore. As I motivated before, perhaps it is sufficient in your domain to add the unique identifier of an `User` (its name, login or email-address) to the `Comment` only, which enables you to keep a `Comment` even if the `User` gets removed. Its a matter of what you want to achieve.

Comment: Please check this class diagram, any comments? ![Class Diagram](http://img.im/i/gc2wy8)

Comment: Is `UserInfo` a replication of `User`, reduced to information required by `Comment`? If, it is a way to conserve information while allowing the deletion of `Users`, at the cost of keeping `UserInfo` and `User` in sync. Its a tradeoff not to underestimate. Replication may cause some headaches. But in case you can live with minor inconsistency it shouldn't be an issue. Having many database tables implies many joins, which may result in bad performance. Hence consider embedding the `UserInfo` into the `Comment` class. Its another tradeoff between redundancy and performance.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. I think logically, Job should have Comments. And the relationship should be composition. Comments will be based on job, if Job doesn't
>      exist, then there is no point of having comments.

Answer (score 1):

There are various semantics I've seen over the years for aggregation and composition, but UML's have become something of a de facto standard.

UML states that an **aggregation** relationship indicates a whole part relationship which is "transitive and anti-symmetric".  The "transitive" part means that if C is part-of B and B is part-of A, then C is part-of A, which makes intuitive sense.  The "anti-symmetric" part means that you cannot have cycles in the aggregation graph, meaning that an object may not be directly or indirectly part of itself, which also makes sense intuitively.

**Composition** (or "composite aggregation" as UML terms it) is aggregation with the additional constraints of "strong ownership" (a part may only be part of one composite at a time) and "coincident lifetimes" (so parts contained within a composite at the time of its deletion are deleted with it).

For Job and Comment, in my judgement it is definitely composition because a comment wouldn't be shared between jobs and when you remove a job you would remove its comments at the same time.

Comment: How about comments and user ?

Comment: You mean what happens if you have User in the domain model and comments are created by Users and associated with Jobs?  In that case you need to choose.  Personally I think that's probably still composition between Job and Comment with an association from User to Comment, but there's no right answer.  Perhaps comments are "owned" by users and associated to from Jobs.  That's fine too - depends how you want to model it.  The complication when you have Job and User referencing Comment is the need to clearly state the invariants you want to ensure model integrity when jobs or users are deleted.